# How to track user playtime in a specific game | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to design a bot that would track how long server members have played Rocket League in the current week, and will display a leaderboard either at the end of the week or whenever a "!leaderboard" command is called. I'm not sure how to go about this, would anyone mind helping me get on the right track? I'm particularly struggling with how to detect when a user has started playing Rocket League.

For a bit more explanation, the bot needs to:

1. detect when a user is playing rocket league
2. track the users playtime during a period of one week
3. generate a playtime leaderboard of server members on command

Answer (score 2):

I believe Discord's official API does not provide a method to track a user's game activity duration, but there is a way around it.

Discord allows a bot to see when a user starts playing a game by changing their status. You can detect the change and start a timer. When the user stops playing the game (which you can check by polling their status at regular intervals), you can stop the timer and calculate the playtime.

This is how you could do this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.presences = True 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

tracked_game = 'Rocket League'
timers = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    # Check if the member started playing a game
    if (not before.activity or before.activity.name != tracked_game) and (after.activity and after.activity.name == tracked_game):
        timers[after.id] = datetime.now()
        print(f"{after} started playing {after.activity.name}")
    # Check if the member stopped playing a game
    elif before.activity and before.activity.name == tracked_game and (not after.activity or after.activity.name != tracked_game):
        start_time = timers.pop(after.id, None)
        if start_time:
            playtime = datetime.now() - start_time
            print(f"{after} played {tracked_game} for {playtime}")

@bot.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    # TODO: Implement leaderboard functionality
    pass

bot.run('your bot token')
```

I have left the leaderboard functionality as you'll need a database or some sort of storage to keep track of everything. You could use something like SQLite or even just plain JSON / a txt file.